# How can I fix LNK2019 with CMake and GLAD?

Tags: c++, cmake, glad

I am trying to make a project that utilises OpenGL via GLAD and GLFW, however I am stuck at a problem which is every time I try to build and run my application, it fails with

`LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gladLoadGLLoader referenced in function "public: __cdecl IrixRenderer::IrixRenderer(void)" (??0IrixRenderer@@QEAA@XZ)`

My project is structured like so:

```
Nexus/
├─ Nexus/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ Irix/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

The source for the root CMakeLists.txt is

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("Nexus")

# Add include directories.
include_directories ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/include")

# Add link directories.
link_directories ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/lib")

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("Nexus")

add_subdirectory ("Irix")

add_subdirectory ("Solaris")
```

and the source for the Irix/CMakeLists.txt file is

```
add_library(Irix STATIC "Irix.cpp" "Irix.h")

# Find the OpenGL package.
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# Link against GLFW, OpenGL, GLM and freetype.
target_link_libraries(Irix glfw3 ${OPENGL_PACKAGE} freetype)
```

I have tried switching from `target_link_libraries(Irix glfw3 opengl32 freetype)` to the `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)` and `${OPENGL_PACKAGE}` alternative, however that did not work.

I also tried searching for similar problems, however none of the results were satisfactory, and they did not fix the problem I had.

Comment: You need to link glad.

Comment: I cannot link GLAD as it doesn't have a .lib file. It's a header only. @user7860670

Comment: It is not header-only. If you don't have a .lib file then you'll need to make it yourself.

Comment: I know what I downloaded. I got it directly from [here](https://glad.dav1d.de/), it only gave me an include folder **because it is header only**.

It had no issue running without CMake, in a standard Visual Studio solution file.

Comment: glad version supplied at the linked website is not header-only, you should recheck the files you've downloaded.

Comment: Again, it worked entirely fine with the header only, in a VS solution, it ran just fine. It was only after switching to CMake that it stopped working.

Comment: If it was working in VS solution then it means that your assumption that it was header-only is simply wrong.

Comment: But it did not have a lib file for VS, I gave CMake the exact same dependencies folder that VS had. The only difference is the fact that the project uses CMake rather than VS solutions.

Comment: Most likely you've compiled `glad.c` file along with your project rather than building it as a separate static library and then linking it. Anyway, it would be better for you to focus now on linking missing glad object files rather than arguing that glad is header-only.

Comment: The referenced generator generates both `glad/glad.h` **header** file under `include/` directory and `glad.c` **source** file under `src/` directory. You need to add that `glad.c` into your executable.